# Making import statements explicit

Tags: python, django, import

I was running an app on django's local server, and I was able to use import statements without using the project's directory:

```
from userprofile.views import Profile
```

However, now that I've transferred it to an apache server, it is throwing an error if I use the above import, and will only work if I include the full path from the project:

```
from myproject.userprofile.views import Profile
```

What is the reason for this difference, and why is this required? Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the directory layout on the production server? Or did you change the PATHONPATH in your settings file but maybe only when DEBUG == True? I think without more information, this is hard to guess...

Comment: related PEP http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` looks in every directory in [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) for the specified module (`userprofile/__init__.py` in your case).

If you compare the values of `sys.path` on the two systems, you'll see it is missing the `myproject` directory. You can simply add it to the `sys.path` list.

Comment: Thank you -- and is sys.path` usually added to the .wsgi file, or should it go elsewhere?

Comment: @David 542 Usually, `sys.path` should already have been set up. Adding it to the .wsgi file (with trickery like `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'myproject-source')`) is fine.